# <div> center aligned not working in IE browser

Tags: css

It works in all browsers except one. I want this div to be in the center of a page

```
<div style="padding-left: 800px;">
    <a class="works-top" href="/page/1"></a>
    <a class="free-top" href="/page/2"></a> 
    <a class="faq-top" href="/page/3"></a> </div>
```

Thats how I define it is in the css

```css
a.free-top {
   display:block;
   cursor:pointer;
   background:url(../img/free.png) no-repeat left top;
   width:100px;
   height:20px;
   text-indent:-5000px;
   margin-left:0px;
   margin-top:0px;
   margin-bottom:4px;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `padding-left:800px;` on

```
<div style="padding-left: 800px;">
```

Use `margin:0 auto; and width:1000px;`

Remember that `margin:0 auto;` works only if width is specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `margin: 0 auto;` in order to align your div at the center.

Answer (score 1):

A simple logic without introducing new code, try 
`<div style="padding-left: 50%;">`